# Django i18n issue on heroku

Tags: django, heroku, internationalization

I am developing a Django web application and deploy this application to heroku.
I use i18n to implement multi-language function.
this is my po file

**/locale/zh_hant/LC_MESSAGES/django.po**

```
#: lib/templates/langs/index.html:7
msgid "name"
msgstr "名稱"

#: myShopCar/settings.py:211
msgid "German"
msgstr "德文"

#: myShopCar/settings.py:212
msgid "English"
msgstr "英文"

#: myShopCar/settings.py:213
msgid "Tranditional Chinese"
msgstr "繁體中文"

#: myShopCar/settings.py:214
msgid "Simplied Chinese"
msgstr "簡體中文"
```

this is my template

**/lib/templates/langs/index.html**

```
{% load i18n %}

{% get_current_language as LANGUAGE_CODE %}

{{ LANGUAGE_CODE }}

{% trans "name" %}
{% trans "login" %}
```

it works well and translates correctly on my computer and heroku.

later, i execute the command

> django-admin makemessages -l zh_hant

, then **msgid "login"** was added to django.po, and I changed **msgstr "名稱" to msgstr "名字"**

**/locale/zh_hant/LC_MESSAGES/django.po**

```
#: lib/templates/langs/index.html:8
msgid "login"
msgstr "登入"

#: lib/templates/langs/index.html:7
msgid "name"
msgstr "名字"

#: myShopCar/settings.py:211
msgid "German"
msgstr "德文"

#: myShopCar/settings.py:212
msgid "English"
msgstr "英文"

#: myShopCar/settings.py:213
msgid "Tranditional Chinese"
msgstr "繁體中文"

#: myShopCar/settings.py:214
msgid "Simplied Chinese"
msgstr "簡體中文"
```

it also works well on my computer.

[image: on my computer]

then i deployed my application to heroku, but it doesn't works correctly on heroku this time.

[image: heroku]

it seems that heroku did not reload the new .mo file after new deploy.

Is there anything I lost? thank you for your help...

Comment: Are you sure the application restarted after your final deploy? The mo file is a binary file loaded initially at your application start. So the application server must be restarted after changes to po/mo files.

Comment: i have executed the command "heroku restart" and clicked the button "restart all dynos" on the heroku dashboard. but i am not sure if this command will restart my application? let me check it...

Comment: @devdob i have just tried the following commands to restart my application,
heroku ps:restart web.1 
heroku ps:restart web
is it the right commands to restart application?

Comment: Yes should be. Are you running Nginx or Apache? or just your manage.py command? Also, are you sure your .po file does't have any `#fuzzy` translations?

Comment: @devdob, thank you for your reply, I just run python manage.py runserver on my computer.  yes, i found there is a line '#, fuzzy' in my .po file. 


#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"

Comment: You need to remove/fix the fuzzy translations and compile your messages again. Then all should work fine.

Comment: @devdob, restarting is part of the deployment process on Heroku. OP, you don't need to restart anything manually.

Comment: @devdob, i will try to fix the fuzzy translations today. thank you very much...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue with you.
If you rename the locale folder from zh_hant to zh_Hant
It should be work!